# Are Amazon Prime memberships per region or do they share across all of Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I signed up for the free trial of Amazon Prime on amazon.it (Italy). For a price of 10€/**year** I would get free 2-3 days deliveries on eligible items, and I've successfully used it once.

Now there is an item I need that I can't find on amazon.it but I can find it on both .co.uk (UK) and .de (Germany). I signed in there, but they are still offering me a free trial of Prime.

Is the login the same for all Amazons, but Prime specific to a single region?

(I've also noticed .co.uk offers Prime at 80£/year, which is 10x the price it has on .it. did they misspell something somewhere?)

Comment: Given that I've just noticed that it doesn't include international shipping, I'd guess that having it specific to each region might make sense. However I'm still very confused by the pricing.

Comment: I know that Prime for Amazon JP is not shared with Amazon US, as the two use separate accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. The UK price for Prime seems almost in line with the USA one ($99) and the difference with the Italian Prime seems to be in the services. The [UK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DBYBNEE) for example includes:

> Free Two-Day Shipping, plus exclusive access to movies, music and Kindle books.
>   Unlimited music streaming
>   Watch unlimited movies and TV shows with Prime Instant Video
>   A Prime membership includes over 500,000 free ebooks

whereas (as far as I can tell - you would know better!) the Italian Prime seems to be only the speedy/cheaper delivery.

So I suggest (a) specific to a 'region' and (b) not a typo.